# $\bigcap_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J_i}A_j$ -- how does intersection distribute over union?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The title basically states my question: I have an intersection over a union where the index of the union depends on the index of the intersection, in particular: how can I distibute the intersection over the union in this example $\bigcap_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J_i}A_j$ ? (I am looking for something like this $\bigcup_{??}\bigcap_{??}A_{??}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a general formula. Let us denote by $P(j, x)$ the property $x\in A_j$ and $Q(i, j)$ the property $j\in J_i$. Let $J = \bigcup_{i\in I}J_i$ Then the property $\displaystyle x\in X:=\bigcap_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J_i} A_j$ can be rephrased as

$$\forall i\in I, \exists j\in J, P(j, x) \wedge Q(i, j)$$

Note that the properties $P$ and $Q$ can be practically anything. I don't believe it can be valuably reformulated as a proposition starting with $\exists$, which would be the case if it could be written as a set union.

**Edit** Thinking again, there is a rather artificial way to do this: the above proposition says that for each $i$, there is a $j$ satisfying some property. It means that we choose a $j$ for each $i$ and it can be rephrased as saying that we pick once a single [choice function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice), that is to say an element of the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) $\prod_{k\in I}J_k$. Thus we can write
$$
X = \bigcup_{z\in\prod_{k\in I}J_k}\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{\pi_i(z)}
$$
where $\pi_i$ is the $i$-th projection map of the cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in probability theory, the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ is defined in this way.

Second, for simplicity, let's see $\cap_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\cup _{j\geq i} A_j$. $A_n$ are sets.
For example,
\begin{align}
A_1 &= \{a,b,c\} \\
A_2 &= \{a,b\} \\
A_3 &= \{a,c\} \\
A_4 &= \{a,b,c\} \\
A_5 &= A_2, A_6=A_3, \dots
\end{align}
Of course, you do not have to have periodical $A_n$, but I set it this way for easy demonstration. Now, for some $i$, $\cup _{j\geq i} A_j = \{a,b,c\}$ because this is the union of all sets after $A_i$. Thus, $\cap_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\cup _{j\geq i} A_j = \{a,b,c\}$ since $\cup _{j\geq i} A_j $ are the same for all $i$.

Interesting thing is, if I add $d$ to $A_1$ but keep the other $A_n's$ unchanged, $\cup _{j\geq 1} A_j = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\cup _{j\geq 2} A_j = \{a,b,c\}$. 
Then $\cap_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\cup _{j\geq i} A_j = \{a,b,c, d\} \cap \{a,b,c\}\cap \{a,b,c\}\cap\dots = \{a,b,c\}$